# How to add custom user agent to flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I have to add a custom webview user agent for QR code scanner like this `userAgent: 'random'` in this webview widget:

```
  Widget webView() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        BeWebView(url: urlFound, general: General(), callback: (webView) {}, onPageFinish: () {}, options: widget.options),
        backButton(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Where to put the `userAgent: 'random'` code part?

Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:app_mobile/helpers/font_helper.dart';
import 'package:app_mobile/models/app_options.dart';
import 'package:app_mobile/models/be_contact.dart';
import 'package:app_mobile/models/general.dart';
import 'package:app_mobile/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/contact.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';

class QRCodeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const QRCodeScreen({Key? key, required this.options, required this.general}) : super(key: key);
  final AppOptions options;
  final General general;
  @override
  State<QRCodeScreen> createState() => _QRCodeScreenState();

}

class _QRCodeScreenState extends State<QRCodeScreen> {
  MobileScannerController cameraController = MobileScannerController();
  bool hasURL = false;
  bool hasVCard = false;
  bool hasText = false;
  String urlFound = "";
  String textMessage = "";
  BeContact contact = BeContact();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (hasURL) {
      return webView();
    } else if (hasVCard) {
      return contactInfo();
    } else if (hasText) {
      return textInfo();
    } else {
      return mobileScanner();
    }
  }

  Widget mobileScanner() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        MobileScanner(
            allowDuplicates: true,
            controller: cameraController,
            onDetect: (barcode, args) {
              final String? code = barcode.rawValue;
              String text = code ?? "";
              if (text.startsWith("https") || text.startsWith("http") || text.startsWith("www")) {
                setState(() {
                  hasURL = true;
                  urlFound = code ?? "";
                });
              } else if (code!.contains("VCARD")) {
                setState(() {
                  hasVCard = true;
                  var mainContact = Contact.fromVCard(code);
                  contact = BeContact().fromContact(mainContact);
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  hasText = true;
                  textMessage = code;
                });
              }
            }),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    icon: ValueListenableBuilder(
                      valueListenable: cameraController.torchState,
                      builder: (context, state, child) {
                        switch (state as TorchState) {
                          case TorchState.off:
                            return const Icon(Icons.flash_off, color: Colors.grey);
                          case TorchState.on:
                            return const Icon(Icons.flash_on, color: Colors.yellow);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    iconSize: 26.0,
                    onPressed: () => cameraController.toggleTorch(),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    icon: ValueListenableBuilder(
                      valueListenable: cameraController.cameraFacingState,
                      builder: (context, state, child) {
                        switch (state as CameraFacing) {
                          case CameraFacing.front:
                            return const Icon(Icons.camera_front);
                          case CameraFacing.back:
                            return const Icon(Icons.camera_rear);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    iconSize: 26.0,
                    onPressed: () => cameraController.switchCamera(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage(
              "images/camera_overlay.png",
            ),
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget webView() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        BeWebView(url: urlFound, general: General(), callback: (webView) {}, onPageFinish: () {}, options: widget.options),
        backButton(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget contactInfo() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                contact.name,
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: getFontStyle(20, Colors.black, FontWeight.normal, widget.general),
              ),
              Text(
                contact.title,
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: getFontStyle(16, Colors.black, FontWeight.bold, widget.general),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              contactRow(contact.phone, const Icon(Icons.phone)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              contactRow(contact.email, const Icon(Icons.email)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              contactRow(contact.website, const Icon(Icons.link)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              contactRow(contact.address, const Icon(Icons.pin_drop)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              contactRow(contact.city, const Icon(Icons.location_city)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              contactRow(contact.country, const Icon(Icons.pin_drop)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        backButton(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget textInfo() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: Text(
              textMessage,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              maxLines: 10,
              style: getFontStyle(18, Colors.black, FontWeight.bold, widget.general),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backButton()
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget contactRow(String text, Icon icon) {
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10), bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 2,
            blurRadius: 4,
            offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            icon,
            Text(
              text,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: getFontStyle(16, Colors.black, FontWeight.bold, widget.general),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget backButton() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: MaterialButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          elevation: 0,
          color: Colors.white70,
          highlightElevation: 0,
          minWidth: double.minPositive,
          height: double.minPositive,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (mounted) {
              setState(() {
                cameraController = MobileScannerController();
                urlFound = "";
                textMessage = "";
                hasVCard = false;
                hasURL = false;
                hasText = false;
              });
            }
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code related to `BeWebView` method https://pastebin.com/GNNbyefh

Comment: Can you provide source code for `BeWebView`method?

Comment: @Alaindeseine This is the code related to `BeWebView` https://pastebin.com/GNNbyefh

Answer (score 2):

Looks like user agent is passed in `general` parameter.

```
InAppWebViewOptions(
  userAgent: widget.general.customUserAgent ? widget.general.customUserAgentString : "",
...
),
```

Add `customUserAgent` and `customUserAgentString` to general.

```
BeWebView(url: urlFound, general: General(????), ...),
```

Comment: Sorry I am not sure where to add this, this is my first Flutter experience. Can you please show where to add it by a short example in the code given in my post?

Answer (score 1):

The `userAgent` option is available in the `InAppWebViewOptions` object

```
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
    ...
    userAgent: YOUR_USER_AGENT,
    ...
  ),
),
```

**EDIT :**
In your case, it looks like you're using a model called `General` to hold some values.
You're creating a new instance of this model in this snippet :

```
Widget webView() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        BeWebView(url: urlFound, general: General(), callback: (webView) {}, onPageFinish: () {}, options: widget.options),
        backButton(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

So the content of this class is either full of hardcoded values and you'll be fine (it isn't recommended at all in any programming language), or it'll be empty..

If your General model isn't full of hardcoded values, you have to init it :

```
Widget webView() {
    final general = General();
    general.customUserAgent = YOU_CUSTOM_AGENT;
    general.customUserAgentString  = YOU_CUSTOM_AGENT_STRING_VALUE;

    return Stack(
      children: [
        BeWebView(url: urlFound, general: general, callback: (webView) {}, onPageFinish: () {}, options: widget.options),
        backButton(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is not working on qr scan page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. The snippet linked above should be added to your ```BeWebView``` widget

Comment: @twelvell I updated my answer. By now you should have all the elements to fix your problem.